# Can the <select> element be nested inside a <label> element?

Tags: html, select, label

Free Code Camp Learn HTML says this code is incorrect even though it is exactly what the instructions said to do.

````
```<label>How did you hear about us?
  <select>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
  </select>
</label>```
````

I must be missing something really simple.

Comment: Did you not run it through the W3C validator before asking here?

Comment: Yes I did. That just told me there was not doctype (duh) and the option elements were empty. So no help from the validator.

Comment: I just ran it through the validator and it lists five errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put <select> element in <label>. The error may be caused by the empty <option> tags. Try putting values in the <option> elements. You can also try to put "for" attribute in the label tag. The value of the for attribute must match the id of the select element.

```
   <label>How did you hear about us?
   <select>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
    </select>
    </label>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions and still no joy. It must be a Free Code Camp glitch. Unfortunately, it prevents you from moving on to the next step.

Comment: can you provide the link to that challange or section?

Comment: Here is the link: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/2022/responsive-web-design/learn-html-forms-by-building-a-registration-form/step-35

Comment: I have edited the code . It passed.